# UTI that's exclusive to my app and doesn't show dropbox on open with dialogue

Tags: ios

I've defined a custom UTI for an iOS app and transferring files via AirDrop. Its all working as it should, except that on the receiving device the user is offered a choice of apps such as DropBox, Evernote, etc in addition to my app. I'd like to prevent this, so the user is only shown my app as the choice. Is this possible?

In my info.plist I have:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Text</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.me.text</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My Text</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.me.text</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>per</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to assert your will over the user; that never ends well.

Your problem isn't actually caused on your end, tho':

DropBox, Evernote et. al. are probably declaring their own schemes where they allow *all* files; and the system acts appropriately, giving a list of all matching applications (which will always contain applications that declare `*`).

In other words, what you are attempting to do is:

1. Impossible
2. Not intended by the design
3. Deeply antisocial

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself. I did it by changing the exported type to be based on public.data.

This is a logical thing to do because the file exported by my app makes no sense to be consumed by Evernote, etc. I was incorrect in specifying it as text, because that would have really confused the user - pushing a dialog that gave them them options that were illogical. Contrary to claims of another poster here, this isn't a case of "exerting my will over the user" but of mistakenly specifying a structured file meant for another program to parse as a text file. Basing on public.data fixes this and now the user has a better experience.

My UTExportedTypeDeclations now looks like this for others that might be interested:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My Text</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.me.text</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>per</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```